# Find the potential $\Phi$ and the field $\mathbf{F} = \nabla \Phi$ for a two-dimensional dipole at the origin.

Tags: analysis, problem-solving, vector-fields

I'm struggling with one of the problems from mathematical analysis II course. 
The problem is next:

Find the potential $\Phi$ and the field $\vec{\mathbf{F}} = \nabla \Phi$ for a two-dimensional dipole at the origin. with axis in the $z$ direction and dipole moment *$μ$* 

Unfortunately I'm unable to evaluate it at all and I would love to see the solution and explanation about what is happening here and in the solution.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: You have to provide much more detail and effort. What is a 2-D dipole with axis in the $z$ direction and dipole moment $\mu$? We are not a homework solution site.

Comment: First of all, I want to say that this is a Q&A site for math and as I stated in the question, I was unable to do anything in the problem, and the reason is that I couldn't quite understand those concepts. Now I could have written my understandings of them but there was possibility that I would make some mistakes and I do think explaining concepts wrongly is worse than not writing them. Beside all of this I am new to writing questions publicly and especially on this site so I will take that suggestion and write more precise questions in the future and as I know understand this problem and

Comment: I will provide much more detailed information in the question, and I will write the answer also.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to say is that, saying something like that as you said at the end of your comment can affect someone so much and give them anxiety and kill someone's curiosity. They may be shamed to write questions and so on. I would suggest to use words more carefully to not harm others. This isn't site for toxicity or anything related to it. We are here to help each other and I myself don't have any intention to take others time to make my homework. the reason for which I didn't elaborated question with much more details was that I didn't want to wrote concepts wrongly as I stated

Comment: In the above comment. Now thank you for the suggestion and as I said I will edit question and post the answer as soon as I will be able to.

Answer (score 2):

The field of a dipole is essentially taking the limit of the field of two oppositely charged particles separated by a distance $\vec d$ as they come closer but in a way where the product $q \vec d$ converges to the dipole moment $\vec \mu$. So it is taking the limit of the potential field but in a very particular and specific way. The context I use is electrostatics but the same principle applies to any potential field, where $q$ would be point sources. 
Specifically, given the potential field of a positively-charged particle centered at the origin to be $q\phi(\vec r)$, where $q$ is the charge and $\phi$ is field per unit charge (for convenience, will be clear below), the field generated by two particles (one positive, one negative) located at opposite sides of the origin is just
$$\varphi (\vec r) = q\phi(\vec r-\frac{1}{2}\vec d) - q\phi(\vec r +\frac{1}{2} \vec d) $$
(since the field of a negative charge centered at origin is just $-q\phi(\vec r)$). Taylor expansion to first order
$$\phi(\vec r-\frac{1}{2}\vec d) = \phi(\vec r)- \frac{1}{2} \nabla \phi(\vec r) \cdot \vec d + \mathcal{O}(|\vec d|^2)$$
$$\phi(\vec r+\frac{1}{2}\vec d) = \phi(\vec r)+ \frac{1}{2} \nabla \phi(\vec r) \cdot \vec d + \mathcal{O}(|\vec d|^2)$$
Combining we get
$$\varphi(\vec r)=-\nabla \phi(\vec r) \cdot q\vec d + q \:\mathcal{O}(|\vec d|^2)$$
I mentioned that a dipole is just the field of two oppositely charged particles as they are brought together and $q \vec d $ converges to $\vec \mu$ in the limit, i.e. the charge $q$ is increasing to infinity while the distance $\vec d$ is decreasing to zero but in such a way that their product converges to $\vec \mu$. This means that as the charges are brought together ($\vec d \rightarrow 0$ while $q \vec d \rightarrow \vec \mu$) the field of a dipole becomes
$$\varphi_{d}(\vec r)=\nabla \phi (\vec r) \cdot \vec \mu$$
since
$$\lim_{q \vec d \rightarrow \vec \mu \\ \vec d \rightarrow 0} q \: \mathcal{O}(|\vec d|^2) = 0$$
So all you have to do is evaluate the gradient $\nabla \phi$ and insert it in the formula above. In electrostatics, for a charge in 3D, $\phi$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{|\vec r|}$ while for 2D, $\phi$ is proportional to $\ln(|\vec r|)$, so the gradients will be proportional to $\frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|^3}$ in 3D and $\frac{\vec r}{|\vec r|^2}$ in 2D. Your application might be different (so $\phi $ might be different) but the procedure is essentially the same. 
Lastly, if you're assuming the dipole is orientation along the z-direction, then you're assuming $\vec d = d \: \hat{z}$ where $\hat{z}$ is a basis vector pointing in the z-direction, and then the moment is given by $\vec \mu = \mu \hat{z}$ so substituting into the formula, you get
$$\varphi_d(\vec r) = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \mu$$

Comment: Thank you so much